# Crystal Reports Exibindo valores estranhos

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

Estou iniciando em CR e estou com uma dificuldade na geração de um relatório no Crystal Reports do visual studio 2008. Ele não esta exibindo os valores da minha tabela do banco de dados.

O datasource que estou utilizando no relatório é o Dataset da aplicação, ou seja, o dataset que aparece nas connections ao clicar em Set DataSource. E ao abrir a base .mdf no Sql Server Management os registros estão lá.

Criei o relatorio com o Wizard do report, agrupando por idOrcamento. Até criei uma Stored Procedure, porém nao consegui vincular ao relatório.

Segue Imagens:
DataSource:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Design Report:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Me ajudem estou nessa a mais de uma semana, e não quero desistir.

Comment: Qual é o problema? O que acontece quando você executa a aplicação e tenta mostrar o relatório?

Comment: Ele imprime o relatório, porém, não exibe as informações do banco, apenas do parametro que passei para o relatorio trabalhar com o select expert.  Veja como esta o codigo e o resultado: [ http://imgur.com/a/4CB7z ]

Comment: O IDOrçamento que você esta passando, deve estar nulo, passe um valor fixo para testar sem pegar de frmOrçamento.

Comment: Boa noite, tentei passando um valor fixo, e infelizmente nao deu certo..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, criei uma DataTable e a populei com uma query em sql, em seguida invoquei o relatório utilizando essa datatable como datasource, e funcionou!

Obrigado a todos pela ajuda !